# java.lang.VerifyError: class frameless.functions.Spark2_4_LambdaVariable overrides final method genCode

Tags: scalapb

I am running a databricks job that uses ProtoSQL.udf.
The data frame has a column that has encoded protoValue. The parse method is used to create a new column which stores json extracted from protoValue.

scalaVersion = 2.12
scalapb.version = 0.11.8

Using below dependencies

> implementation "com.thesamet.scalapb:sparksql32-scalapb0_11_2.12:1.0.0-M1"
> implementation "com.thesamet.scalapb:scalapb-json4s_2.12:0.11.0" 
> implementation "com.thesamet.scalapb:scalapb-runtime_2.12:0.11.8"

getting the below error during runtime at ProtoSQL.udf

> java.lang.VerifyError: class
> frameless.functions.Spark2_4_LambdaVariable overrides final  method
> genCode.(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/codegen/CodegenContext;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/codegen/ExprCode;

Stacktrace

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m;
> support was removed in 8.0 22/02/25 11:00:28 ERROR Uncaught throwable
> from user code: java.lang.VerifyError: class
> frameless.functions.Spark2_4_LambdaVariable overrides final method
> genCode.(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/codegen/CodegenContext;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/codegen/ExprCode;
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:757)   at
> java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)     at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)    at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)     at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ClassLoaders$LibraryClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.scala:151)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)    at
> frameless.functions.FramelessUdf$.apply(Udf.scala:220)    at
> scalapb.spark.Udfs.$anonfun$udf$1(Udfs.scala:12)  at
> com.atlassian.plato.jobs.jira.reader.ProtoParser.parse(ProtoParser.scala:21)
>
> [image]

```
  def parse(df: DataFrame)(implicit entityCompanion: EntityCompanion): DataFrame = {
    implicit val messageEncoder: typedEncoders.GeneratedMessageEncoder = GeneratedMessageEncoder.encoder()
    val parseProto = ProtoSQL.udf { (protoValue: String) =>
      entityCompanion.parseFrom(Base64.getDecoder.decode(protoValue))
    }
    val parsedDf = df.withColumn("value", parseProto(col("payload.protoValue")))
    parsedDf
  }

}

object EntityMapper {
  type EntityCompanion = GeneratedMessageCompanion[_ <: GeneratedMessage]

  def getEntityCompanionObject(entityType: String): EntityCompanion = {
    EntityFactory.getEntity(entityType).getCompanion()
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like an incompatibility due to a install problem. Two versions (of _Spark_?) are mixing themselves. Can you check if your environment can have such problem?

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using? I recently came across that 3.2.1 was incompatible with 3.2.0 and that could lead to some problems. I recommend trying 3.1 for now.

Comment: Using spark 3.2.0

Comment: Can't downgrade to spark 3.1. Also found this thread about frameless https://github.com/bmc/spark-frameless-talk-2018/issues/1 . not sure if it's similar.

Comment: @thesamet , I edited my post with more details. Is there any other approach that I can follow other than using spark 3.1

Comment: The error claims that frameless tries to override `def genCode` but it is final. I searched Spark code and the method doesn't appear to be final. I suspect something in your environment (maybe databricks or another library) is modifying Spark in a way that causes this. Can you try to reproduce this without databricks? If possible, can you fork sparksql-scalapb and add a test case that demonstrates this failure - once you send it as a PR I will be able to reproduce locally and see what a fix might be.

Comment: any update on this? I ran into the same issue on databricks. using spark 3.1.2. scalapb 0.11.8 scala 2.12. thanks!